# mapping of intranet Ip to the static ip which is a server

Tags: apache, jsp, tomcat, servlets, server

i have a  apache server on say static ip 172.10.250.260 and from client machine one  can access the webpage to that mapped to server.

Now from server i can access a webpage page hosted 10.24.250.260 which is on intranet.

how to prgram in jsp or java or on server so that from client machine one can get the accces to that webpage in 10.24.250.260

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html) in apache on  172.10.250.260 machine and in your case it will be something like this

```
ProxyPass        "/internalServer" "http://10.24.250.260/"
```

And you can access to internal server content using http://172.10.250.260/internalServer

Comment: how to mod proxy in Apache tomcat server in eclipse??

Comment: You wrote that you have Apache server on 172.10.250.260 and you can do this in httpd.conf file.

Comment: i am using mod proxy in in httpd , ProxyPass        "/internalServer" "http://10.24.250.260/...."...  . i am getting a error msg displayed file not found  but when i am using  ProxyPass "/internalServer" "http://www.google.com" it is working fine.

Comment: Maybe you need also `ProxyPassReverse        "/internalServer" "http://10.24.250.260/"`

Comment: how to use websockify in httpd.conf. actually i need to mod proxy for vnc..what to do